# Notepad ++: Cannot remove empty line

Tags: regex, notepad++, line

My txt file looks like this:

```
line 1    

line3
```

I'm trying to remove the empty line. I choose "extended" search mode in Notepad++'s Replace window and type `\r\n` or `\n\r` but cannot match it. So, how to do it? I have removed empty lines from a lot of files successfully, but now I cannot remove this one.

Comment: this is a known issue with notepad++ and matching via regex multi-line as well...

Comment: May be, just `\r` or `\n` helps? Windows uses `\r\n`, Linux `\n` and Mac `\r` to indicate the end of a line. Exchanging text files between different OS can have this problem. NP++ has an option to show all invisible characters, this helps to identify it. By the way: For old line printers, carriage return (move printer head to the left) and newline (move the paper) are two separate commands. Hence, Win does it the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex replace operation in **Find in Files** window:

- Find what: `\R*(\R)`
- Replace with: `\1`

---

**EDIT:** To remove last CR/LF, run this **twice** (due to some special CR/LF processing reasons, it consumes only one character per run):

- Find what: `^(.*)\R+$`
- Replace with: `\1`
- Mode: **Regular Expression**
- Option `. matches newline`: **ON**

Comment: It worked but it doesn't remove last empty line ( last empty line is last line )

Comment: @Ban - run appended part twice - please see the edit

Comment: Work like a charm ! Thank you very much, miroxlav !

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with:

Find what: `^\R`
Replace with: `<NOTHING>`

Where `\R` stands for any line break character, `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`.

May be you have spaces in the line, in this case:

Find what: `^\s*\R`
Replace with: `<NOTHING>`

Comment: I am using 6.6.9 Notepad ++

Comment: That's really strange. With the same version it's working pretty well for me.

Comment: Hello, I type \R and it worked but it remove all break line. I only want remove empty line

Comment: @Ban: Sure, but have a try with my last edit: `^\s*\R`

Answer (score 1):

What about menu **Edit** > **Line Operations** > **Remove Empty Lines**? In this case, are you OK with using of built-in functions?

Comment: Hi, I don't see  Remove Empty Lines. Aslo, I have a lot of file. So, I will need regex code to replace.

Comment: Thank you ! It work like a charm. However, I have a lot file. So, I cannot open each file and remove empty line. I need regex code to remove empty line to many files.

Comment: @Ban, OK I also added [regex-based answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27460322/2392157) for you.